# Rails - joining a github project with a missing database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to collaborate on a project which has the following .gitignore:

```
# Ignore bundler config.
/.bundle

# Ignore the default SQLite database.
/db/*.sqlite3
/db/*.sqlite3-journal

# Ignore all logfiles and tempfiles.
/log/*.log
/tmp

# Ignore other unneeded files.
database.yml
doc/
*.swp
*~
.project
.DS_Store
.idea
.secret
```

So the database is missing, along with all the related files, which makes rails throw me an error if I try to start the server, and I also get **rake aborted!** errors if I try to run db:create/migrate/ etc (yml file not found, adapter not specified).

Any pointers at how can I tackle the problem in the most correct/effective way?

Comment: as others have pointed out this is best practice.  create a database.yml and then build from schema/migrations.  I normally replace database.yml with database.dist or the like so others can just cp it over to get a sensible default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're never supposed to supply a database with a project. The normal thing is for you to create it:

1. The database.yml file should define the name of the database, so a `rake db:create` should properly create it for you.
2. The schema should either be defined in the schema.rb file in which case you would run `rake db:schema:load` or it can be provided via migrations (or both). In this second case just run `rake db:migrate`. If migrations are well defined (and they should be), the 2 options are equivalent.
3. If the application also needs some data to run, this should have been placed in the seeds.rb file, which you can load with `rake db:seed`

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest creating a database.yml file with sqlite as the adapter:

```
 development:
   adapter: sqlite3
   database: db/development.sqlite3
   pool: 5
   timeout: 5000
```

Make sure to add `sqlite3` to your Gemfile as well.  Then run `rake db:schema:load` to set up the db from the schema.rb file.

I do this with a "sandbox" environment and have created a simple rake task `rake sandbox:load` to allow designers to easily clone and start up the app to test their front end changes.

Comment: thank you, I created the YML file, ran rake db:create, after that I ran rake db:schema:load, the site started however now I have issues with activeRecord relations

Comment: @DenisG Can you clarify what you mean by activerecord relations issues?

Comment: it's all good now, I wasn't paying attention while filling in the database information. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Add `config/database.yml` file and then run the rake tasks.  Have a look at the following for configuration options for different environments, it uses sqlite so you would need to update the values per your requirement and environment:

```
# SQLite version 3.x
# gem install sqlite3
development:
adapter: sqlite3
database: db/development.sqlite3
pool: 5
timeout: 5000

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
adapter: sqlite3
database: db/test.sqlite3
pool: 5
timeout: 5000

production:
adapter: sqlite3
database: db/production.sqlite3
pool: 5
timeout: 5000
```